A seeds Constraint was violated
Facing error when calling stake function. Can someone explain what am I missing?
I'm running this on Solana playground and calling stake with a random amount and selecting the current wallet for balance , signer and for system program.
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use solana_program::{
    account_info::AccountInfo,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
};

declare_id!("AbZ2ucGsvTMM4tvY7fhfVaYtWZmVrjNm4satpkwwT6fA");

#[program]
mod staking {
    use super::*;

    pub fn stake(ctx: Context<CreateAccount>, amount : u128) -> Result <()>
    {
        let this_account = &mut ctx.accounts.balance;
            this_account.user = ctx.accounts.signer.key();
            this_account.balance += amount;
            Ok(())
    }
    
    pub fn unstake(ctx: Context<CreateAccount>, amount : u128) -> Result <()>
    {
        let this_account = &mut ctx.accounts.balance;
        this_account.balance -= amount;
        Ok(())
    }
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump:u8)]
pub struct CreateAccount<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        space = 500,
        seeds = [signer.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub balance : Account<'info,UserBalance>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


#[account]
pub struct UserBalance{
    pub user : Pubkey,
    pub balance : u128,
}


Seems like you're incorrectly building your transaction when calling this - please add the typescript code calling this

I'm actually running this on Solana playground and calling stake with a random amount and selecting the current wallet for balance and signer while selecting all programs for system program. @Ahri

check balance constrains you are using
#[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        space = 500,
        seeds = [signer.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]

Also #[instruction(bump:u8)] must be #[instruction()] as you are not using taking bump value by your own

there might be the issue with the constrains you are passing in your typescript code

Can you run it on solana playground ? think it should compile there if it can on anchor framework. But I'll try writing  TS test scripts I suppose.
